# Bundler can't find rspec executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bundler

When I try to run my tests in my Rails 5.1 app, I'm getting an error that the executable can't be found:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rspec)
Gem::Exception: can't find executable rspec
  /Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:434:in `block in replace_bin_path'
  /Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

However, when I look in `/Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin`, the executable is there:

```
$ ls /Users/joepalmieri/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin | grep rspec
// => rspec
```

Here are the relevant parts of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.7.2'
end
```

Running `rbenv rehash` didn't help.

Any clue as to the dumb thing have I done to create this madness?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course it was something obvious. I had run `bundle install --without development test` locally to test something. I didn't realize that running `bundle install` (unqualified) after that would repeat the install of the same groups (i.e., it wouldn't install the gems for the `development` and `test` groups).

Running `bundle install --with development test` fixed this.